# Find $7^{2018}-1 \bmod 5$ using Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $z=7^{2018}-1$

> **Theorem.** : *Let $p \in \mathbb{N}$ be any prime and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $p$ doesn't divide $a$, then $p$ divides $a^{p-1}-1$*

$$
z=\left(7^{1009}\right)^2-1=\left(7^{1009}\right)^{3-1}-1
$$
For $p=3$ and $a=7^{1009}$ the theorem gives:
$$
z \bmod 3=0
$$
Any hints on how to proceed to find $z \bmod 5$?

---

**Note:** Some kind of error occurred and the important part of the last sentence got deleted/never composed. I apologize for the ambiguity of my question in its previous form.

Comment: I think you mean "if $p$ doesn't divide $a$".  But why are you working $\pmod 3$ when the question is asking about $\pmod 5$?

Comment: Also a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any hints on how to proceed to find zmod5?

Do it the *EXACT* same way.

$5 -1 = X$

And $2018\div X = Q$ with $R$ remaider.

So $7^{2018}-1 = (7^{Q})^X*7^R - 1 \equiv 7^R - 1 \pmod 5$.

Figuring $7^R-1$ can be done by hand as $7\equiv 2\pmod 5$ so $7^R\equiv 2^R\pmod 7$ and $R < 5$.

.....

But I do have advice:  Don't to $7^{2018} - 1 = (7^{2018})^2 - 1 \equiv 1-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.   Do $7^{2018} -1 = (7^2)^{2018} - 1 \equiv 1^{2018} - 1\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.  It'll make things easier when $2018\div (p-1)$ has a remainder (as it does with $p = 5$)

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$(7^2)^{1009} - 1 \pmod 5$$
$$\equiv (-1)^{1009} - 1$$
$$\equiv -2 \equiv \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]3 \pmod 5$$

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks!

Comment: Is $a^n \equiv (a \bmod 5)^n \, \, (\bmod 5)$ a general rule?

Comment: "Is an≡(amod5)n(mod5) a general rule?"  Yes.  Arithmetic (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and raising things to powers) distributes over modulo.  (Although division requires care; and being powers absolutely does not).  That's a very basic fact you should have proven for yourself long before learning FLT.

Answer (score 1):

$7^{5-1}≡1\mod 5$    ⇒ $7^{2016}=(7^4)^{504} ≡1\mod 5$

$7^2=49 ≡-1\mod 5$

$7^{2}.7^{2016}=7^{2018} ≡-1\mod 5$

⇒ $2^{2018}-1≡-2\mod 5 ≡3\mod 5$